# KnockoutJS options binding, unable to set value in parent context

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
<select data-bind='foreach: theOptions'>
    <option data-bind='text: name, value: $root.watchThis().something'></option>
</select>
You have selected <p data-bind="text: watchThis().something"></p>

Json model.
<p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(watchThis)"></p>
```

Options are being shown, but when i change value the relative observable is not updated.
More code:

```
function FooModel() {
    this.something = ko.observable();   
}

function VM() {
    var self = this;
    self.watchThis = ko.observable(new FooModel());
    self.theOptions = ko.observableArray();

    self.theOptions([
        {id:1, name: 'foo'},
        {id:2, name: 'bar'},
        {id:3, name: 'baz'}
    ]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

I also tried

```
<option data-bind='text: name, value: $root.watchThis().something'></option>
<option data-bind='text: name, value: $root.watchThis.something'></option>
<option data-bind='text: name, value: $parent.watchThis().something'></option>
```

What seems worst, if i explicitly initialize the value like this

```
function FooModel() {
    this.something = ko.observable(2);   
}
```

everything looks fine, but when i switch options the observable is not updated.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gvdP/2)

Question is: how to update an observable from an external context using the option selected value?

Comment: Based on your current question it is very hard to tell what are you trying to achieve and what is not working... can you reformulate your question and/or add more detail about what are you trying to do? Do you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Wqzwh/?

Comment: Yeah! That's exactly what i'm after. I will update question anyway, Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When binding a `select` element, you have to use the `options` direction, not `foreach`:

```
<select data-bind="options: theOptions,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   optionsValue: 'id',
                   value: watchThis().something">
</select>
```

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).

Comment: You can use foreach, you would just not specify the options binding and move the value binding into the select tag

Comment: Thank you mate, i missed the proper meaning of value in select/option bindings.